# Deseret Alphabet in LaTeX?

Tags: typography

Is there a way that I could get the Deseret Alphabet in LaTex?

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SX. XeLaTeX and LuaTeX allow you to use ttf fonts.

Comment: There is an interesting paper on TUGboat about Deseret: https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb25-0/beesley.pdf However, the advertised package and fonts were never published, as far as I know. If you can use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, there are several OpenType or TrueType free fonts that support the Deseret character block.

Comment: @egreg: It's somewhat obscure, but the font can actually be found on Github: https://github.com/ctrlcctrlv/desalph

Answer (score 1):

Unicode contains the characters, and modern TeX engines like `LuaLaTeX` let you use any modern font of your choosing: All you need to do is use a font that supports the required glyphs. A quick search on my system turned up `Segoe UI Symbol`, there are probably many others.

Tested with LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Segoe UI Symbol}

\begin{document}

    Hello, world! , !

\end{document}
```